# Define setter method on property set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to define a setter method that will run on setting a property like:

i want to call

```
object.something = 0;
```

meanwhile in object class i want to achieve something like

```
- (void)setSomething:(NSInteger)something{
    self.something = something;

    // some other work too
}
```

Comment: You seem to have it, except it would be `_something = something;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called property.
you define property in class @interface like:

```
@interface MyClass()
@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass *object;
@end
```

It will automatically create ivar _object, setter and getter for it.
You can override accessor methods. But if you override both setter and getter, you need to synthesize property like:

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize object = _object;
//setter
- (void)setObject:(SomeClass *)object
{
   _object = object;
}
//getter
- (SomeClass *)object
{
   return _object;
}
//class implementation
@end
```

Comment: @trojanfoe, if I understand it right, if you override both accessors, instance variable is not created. Well, if you try not to synthesize property and override set and get, using _object ivar in class implementation will cause compile time error

Comment: @trojanfoe http://imgur.com/cqaG6jy notice, that I've added synthesize. And THAT is what you get without synthesize: http://imgur.com/sM64dfj . And if you do not override both accessor methods, you don't need to synthesize property: http://imgur.com/ru4s4UQ

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I withdraw my comments.  I think I have always provided my own instance variables when overriding both accessors which led to my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak, setter = setSomething:) UIImageView *photoImageView;
```

Anyway, setSomething: is the default method for a property named something. You just need to replace self.something with _something, as pointed in the comments.